# AWS RDS OS Patch

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, patch

Has anyone have a RDS OS Patch upgrade (not RDS instance patch upgrade)? If so I would like to understand the following :

1. When the OS Patch updates, does AWS take a snapshot of the underlying ec2 instance?
2. Does AWS take a backup of the RDS database prior to os patch install.
3. any issues to look out for?

TIA

Comment: Anyone who could answer your first two questions definitively is almost certainly covered by NDA. My _guess_ is that they swap in new hardware, with a new root volume, attaching the data volume from the old instance.

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish? If you are worried about losing your data during an upgrade of an Amazon RDS instance, take a snapshot prior to requesting the upgrade.